# How to apply an alpha mask using Python's svgwrite module?

Tags: python, svg

I'm using the [svgwrite](http://pythonhosted.org//svgwrite/) module to create some images programmatically for  a project. I have the need to use an alpha mask to create graded transparent elements. I'm not clear on how to actually *apply* a mask once it's been created.

In the example below, I'm trying to use a circular gradient to create a graded transparent ring in an otherwise grey square. I can create the square; separately I can create the circular gradient def and a circle filled with it.

Applying the one to the other as a mask I do no understand.

```
def my_mask():
            #  define some params
            width = "500px"
            height = "500px"
            radius = "50%"
            black = "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
            grey = "rgb(127,127,127)"

            #  create the drawing surface
            canvas = svgwrite.Drawing('temp_mask.svg', (width, height))

            #  create defs, in this case, just a single gradient
            rad_grad = canvas.radialGradient(("50%", "50%"), "50%", ("50%", "50%"), id="rad_grad")
            rad_grad.add_stop_color("0%", black, 0)
            rad_grad.add_stop_color("66.6%", black, 255)
            rad_grad.add_stop_color("100%", black, 255)

            #  now to draw; first I create the rect object to be masked
            base_rect = canvas.rect( (0, 0), (width, height), id="masked_rect").fill(grey)
            canvas.add(base)
    
            #  and according to the docs, any SVG fragment can be an alpha mask, so I create this circle
            mask_element = canvas.circle((radius, radius), radius, fill="url(#rad_grad)")

            #  but here's where I get confused; I don't get how this function actually makes use of one element to mask another
            canvas.mask((0, 0), (width, height))

        #  No problem exporting to a file, though. :)
        canvas.save()
```

**Here's what I'm after (red cross just added to demonstrate transparency); easy to do with Sketch**
[image: Example of desired effect]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Jonline! The svgwrite "example" for ClipPath and Mask stops short of actually showing you how to apply it to a drawing. For completeness, I used your method to write a real example for ClipPath:

```python
clip_path = dwg.defs.add(dwg.clipPath(id='my_clip_path1')) #name the clip path
clip_path.add(dwg.circle((5*mm, 5*mm), 10*mm)) #things inside this shape will be drawn
testCircle = dwg.add(dwg.g(id='test', stroke='red', stroke_width=1, fill='black', fill_opacity=1, clip_path="url(#my_clip_path1)"))
testCircle.add(dwg.circle((5*mm, 10*mm), 10*mm))
```

[image: Result of this code]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an inelegant or at least very verbose solution, but, after another hour spent [RTFM](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#Masking) and playing around, the general solution I've come up with is:

1) Define the mask in the SVG defs
2) Add SVG objects to said mask to create the alpha map
3) Reference the mask in, predictably, the mask attribute of the masked object:

Note: I also had the values wrong in my gradients such that they could never have produced the image I included; the code below addresses that as well.

```
def my_mask():
            #  define some params
            width = "500px"
            height = "500px"
            radius = "50%"
            white = "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
            black = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
            grey = "rgb(127,127,127)"

            #  create the drawing surface
            canvas = svgwrite.Drawing('temp_mask.svg', (width, height))

            #  create defs, in this case, just a single gradient
            rad_grad = canvas.radialGradient(("50%", "50%"), "50%", ("50%", "50%"), id="rad_grad")
            rad_grad.add_stop_color("0%", black, 0)
            rad_grad.add_stop_color("66.6%", white, 255)
            rad_grad.add_stop_color("100%", white, 255)
            canvas.defs.add(rad_grad)

            #  create the mask container as a def and include alpha-mapping objects
            mask = canvas.mask((0, 0), (width, height), id="grad_mask")
            mask.add(canvas.rect( (0, 0), (width, height) ).fill(white)
            mask.add(canvas.circle((radius, radius), radius, fill="url(#rad_grad)")
            canvas.defs.add(mask)

            #  now to draw; create the rect object and simply include the mask as an attribute
            base_rect = canvas.rect( (0, 0), (width, height), mask="url(#grad_mask)".fill(grey)
            canvas.add(base)

            #  Still no problem exporting to a file, though. ;)
            canvas.save()
```